# How to fix "default slot raw html rendering in Vue.js component"

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a custom input component and try to use *slot* for pass another element to that component, but when use any html like a simple button inside custom input component tags on the parent component the content render as a raw html(like escaped html text)

I was tried to write html button code inside `<slot></slot>` tag on the custom input component and that's work fine but when pass from parent component broken!

the custom input template is like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="form-group" :class="{ 'ltr ltr-input': ltr }">
    <textarea :id="id" :value="value" @change="input"></textarea>
    <label :for="id">{{ fieldLabel }}</label>
    <slot>
      <button>fallback</button>
    </slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

on the parent element:

```
<TextArea id="message" v-model="message" label="message" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</TextArea>
```

This is screenshot about the result of above code:

[image: slot]

Comment: You shouldn't be using native HTML tags for your Vue component element tags. In the eyes of the parser, `<TextArea>` is the same as `<textarea>` since tags are case-insensitive. Because of this, any content inside your `<TextArea>` component will simply be rendered as a plain string in the native `<textarea>` element. Try to create an MCVE: this is not expected behavior of a `<slot>` component and without any further code it's not possible to pinpoint what has went wrong.

Comment: @Terry thanks you, you save my time, i wasn't know that, just change my component name and everything work's fine thank you, if you post your comment as a answer I will accept it and close this question ;-)

Comment: Consider that done :) glad that I've managed to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more explanation from my comment: you are using a "reserved" element tag word for your Vue component name, which might explain the weirdness you have encountered. Due to the case insensitivity of HTML tag names, `<TextArea>` is simply parsed as `<textarea>` by the web browser, and inherits all the default rendering behavior for that native element. This means that whatever text content that is between your `<TextArea>` tags will simply be rendered as plain text as they would be in a native `<textarea>` element.

To circumvent this issue, you should always strive to name your Vue components to be unique: two-words is a good start, since HTML tag names don't comprise of two words for now. So, you can rename `<TextArea>` to `<custom-textarea>` to `<v-textarea>` and it shoudl work: just remember to update your template name as well.